# What Can I Do if appid and cpid Cannot Be Found During an HMS Core SDK Integration Test?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

After I integrated the  HMS Core SDK  and call the api in the SDK,it failed.And two errors are reported in the log,the first of which is that appid and cpid cannot be found, and the other is the result code 907135000 is reported.
The following error information is recorded in the logs:

```html
E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: In getMetaDataAppId, Failed to read meta data for the AppID.
E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: Get client/app_id failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: agconnect-services.json
E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: The client/app_id is null.
E/SecurityResourcesReader: KEY is null return def directly
I/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: In getMetaDataCpId, Failed to read meta data for the CpId.
E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: Get client/cp_id failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: agconnect-services.json
E/HMSSDK_AGCUtils: The client/cp_id is null.
I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:1, error_code 907135000, api_name:core.getNoticeIntent, app_id:|, pkg_name:com.appservicetest.huawei, session_id:*, transaction_id:000000000Intent20201105190645844381286, resolution:null
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the **agconnect-services.json** file to the **app** directory of your project, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

2. Check whether **applicationId** in the app-level **build.gradle** file shares the same package name as that configured in AppGallery Connect. The name is case sensitive.
3. Go to **buildscript** > **dependencies** in the project-level **build.gradle** file and check whether the AppGallery Connect plug-in configuration has been added.

   Sample code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
}

dependencies {
...
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'
}
}
```

4. Check whether the following configuration has been added to the app-level **build.gradle** file:

**apply plugin**: 'com.huawei.agconnect'

Please note that this configuration must be added to the next line of **apply plugin: 'com.android.application**. Otherwise, an error may occur.

5. If you are releasing a package on multiple platforms, the preceding method may not solve the problem. In this case, you can try this method:

Add the JSON file to the **app** directory and define **appid** and **cpid** in **manifest.json** by adding the following code:

```
<meta-data  
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid"  
    <!-- Replace xxx with the actual app ID, which can be obtained on the App information page. --> -->  
    android:value="appid=xxx">  
</meta-data>
<!-- Replace xxx with the actual payment ID, which can be obtained from the app's IAP information. --> -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.cpid"
    android:value="cpid=xxx">
</meta-data>
```

Query **cpid** in the **agconnect-services.json** file.